# Is there alternative for front() in c++ 03?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

```
   string utf2oem( string const & in_str )  {
      int n = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, in_str.data(), in_str.size(), NULL, 0 ); 
      if( n == 0 ) 
        return in_str; 

      wstring tmp;
      tmp.resize( n );

      int ret = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, in_str.data(), in_str.size(), &tmp.front(), tmp.size() );
      if( ret == 0 )
        return in_str; 

      string out_str;
      out_str.resize( n );

      ret = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP, 0, tmp.data(), n, &out_str.front(), n, NULL, NULL); 

      return( ret == 0 ? in_str : out_str );
    }
```

I try to use this function but get error : `error C2039: 'front' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'`

So can i use something instead front() in Visual C++ 2008 with boost 1.38?

Comment: [`in_str[0]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Front returns first element, so you can [manually refer to it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at). You can acces to element like in a table.

```
&our_str[0] //insted of &our_str.front()
```

Or use the function [.data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) made specifically to this. But remember "Modifying the character array accessed through data is undefined behavior." (from en.cppreference.com)

```
our_str.data()
```

But if you need an iterator to begin, you can use [.begin()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin).

```
our_str.begin()
```

More about strings you can read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Note that mutating the buffer behind `data()` is *not* defined to have correct behavior :)